# Consume multiple messages from a queue in Tibco EMS

Tags: tibco, ems

Is it possible to consume multiple messages in one call from a Tibco EMS queue. I am using the `Receive` method of the `MessageConsumer` class to consume the data currently but this just returns one `Message`. I'm wondering if there's something that returns an array of `Message` objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue should not be treated as an inbound array object... mostly because the number of such objects could be massive... and such behaviors would be in direct contradiction with the basic "atomic information piece" notions of messaging. Queues should really be seen as an input "faucet" providing a flux of information.

That said : You might be looking for the [javax.jms.QueueBrowser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) facility object. It IS in contradiction of typical messaging patterns, but can be useful. (Rules are meant to be broken sometimes, are they not ?)
Here is a link to [many related examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.jms.QueueBrowser). 
EMS is a JMS provider, so these examples can be used with it.

To retrieve specific messages (to put in an array ?), you could then use a ["receive" with message selectors](http://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml) (ex: on the message ID)

UPDATE : There is also this non-jms response : [Use the Native EMS API to purge](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/8.1.0/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/admin/TibjmsAdmin.html#purgeQueue(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thanks GhislainCote - i should have added some context to my question. I'm just looking to flush the queue as fast as possible. I know I could add more threads each consuming one message at a time, but I was hoping one thread could read a chunk of messages off at once (including removing them from the queue). I agree about the number of messages issue - I will look through the message selectors link you sent, hopefully there is some way to just select the first 10 messages for example.

Comment: See the example link for multiple purge examples... Most "purges" I know are either : 1- non jms calls (ex: direct EMS program api, see other answer), or 2 - JMS retreive, one by one, in a loop.